# Reduce network traffic from Stripe API phoning home (in Single Page Application)

Tags: stripe-payments

Using Stripe for payments in our Single Page Application (SPA).

We include the Stripe API using `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` (See https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference)

Works great but it's periodically phoning phoning home by making POST requests to https://m.stripe.com/4

I realise this is part of their fraud detection system but is there a way to reduce this, or perhaps disable it until we enter a shopping/purchasing process? Shopping/purchasing is only one rarely used part of the application so I would prefer to avoid spamming network requests for all users just to support the checkout in some cases.

One imperfect idea: Delay loading the Stripe API (by delaying loading of the script tag) until the user starts shopping/purchasing. Obviously once it's loaded it would start phoning home but at least it would be an improvement.

--

The API seems to be designed more for websites with individual pages, were the Script tag could be included only on shopping-related pages. It seems less geared towards single page applications where the page persists for longer.

Comment: What your seeing is actually [part of Stripe's fraud detection systems](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#including-stripejs). The best practice is to have it load even if you're not yet presenting a payment form.